# How can you list all non-child frames?

Tags: frames

There's `frame-list` but this lists child-frames, and there's `visible-frame-list` but this doesn't list iconified frames.

It seems like there should be a simple function to return all non-child frames.

I suspect it can be hacked together with `filtered-frame-list` but my elisp-fu is not strong enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to filter the frames returned by `frame-list` selecting only the ones that have a null `parent-frame`:

```el
(defun non-child-frame-list ()
  (let ((frames (frame-list)))
    (seq-filter
      (lambda (frame)
        (null (cadr (assoc 'parent-frame (frame-parameters frame)))))
      frames)))
```

You can call it like this `ESC ESC : (non-child-frame-list)`.

Alternatively, as you surmised, you can do it with `filtered-frame-list` with this predicate:

```el
(defun non-child-frame-p (frame)
   (null (cadr (assoc 'parent-frame (frame-parameters frame)))))
```

Then you can do `(filtered-frame-list #'non-child-frame-p)`.